# Can I use the call function command in the debug environment of GDB + GdbServer?

Tags: android, gdb, gdbserver

When I use GDB to debug Android native programs such as SurfaceFlinger, I find that functions cannot be called. For example, I want to see the result of region.isEmpty () : p region.isEmpty (). Errors are generated.

(gdb) p bounds.isEmpty()
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 0.
Cannot access memory at address 0x4000

Command aborted.
An error occurred while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(android::Region::isEmpty() const) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

Comment: What errors are generated?

Comment: The question has been updated